# What is Salat Al Abhar صلاة العبهر?

Tags: salat, source-identification

I have read of this salat online but I can not find a Hadith that mentions it.  What or is there any Hadith mentioning this salat, and what is the authenticity of the Hadith?  Is this salat a Bid'ah?

Comment: Where did you hear about this? That might be a good place to find out more about it. Any more details you provide might be useful.

Comment: Sorry, I read it not heard it.  I read it online , though I do not recall the site.

Comment: I don't know the specifics, but I believe it's something our Shi'a brothers can answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is non-existing in Sunni Islam, and Sunnis would consider it a clear Bid'ah. It bears some resemblance to صلاة التسابيح (Salat At-tasabih), except that in the latter no Surah is repeated, and it has no relation to seeing the Prophet (SAAW).

Salat Al Abhar, as described in @phoenix's answer, has some violations (according to Sunnis):

- Repeating Surahs in prayer is a Bid'ah.
- Repeating Surahs directly after prayer is a Bid'ah.
- Ending with one salam is unreasoned. (This is only specified in Janazah/funeral prayer).
- Expecting a specific reward without proof from Qur'an or Sunnah is unacceptable.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. According to some of the madhaahib, the first tasleem is obligatory, and the second is mustahabb.

Comment: @ashes999 As far as I understand, the second tasleem is not obligatory but normally required. Your prayer is correct if you don't do it, but normally you should.

Comment: yes, we agree about the ruling. The way you wrote it, you called it "unreasoned." That doesn't convey what you inteded.

Answer (score 1):

It is a prayer related from Amir al-Mu'mineen (a) for anyone desirous of seeing the Holy Prophet (saww). In Mustadrak al-Wasa'il, we find this Hadith detailing the method of its performance:

> 7070 / 28 - رأيت في بعض المجاميع، مرويا عن أمير المؤمنين (عليه
>   السلام)، أنه قال: (إني إذا اشتقت إلى رسول الله (صلى الله عليه وآله،
>   أصلي صلاة العبهر (1) في أي يوم كان، فلا أبرح من مكاني حتى أرى رسول
>   الله (صلى الله عليه وآله) في المنام) قال علي بن منهال: جربته سبع مرات،
>   وهي أربع ركعات، يقرأ في كل ركعة: فاتحة الكتاب مرة، وإنا أنزلناه عشر
>   مرات، ويسبح خمس عشرة مرة (سبحان الله والحمد لله ولا إله إلا الله والله
>   أكبر) ثم يركع ويقول ثلاث مرات: سبحان ربي العظيم، ويسبح عشر مرات، ثم
>   يرفع رأسه ويسبح ثلاث مرات، ثم يسجد ويسبح خمس عشرة مرة، ثم يرفع رأسه،
>   وليس فيما بين السجدتين شئ، ثم يسجد ثانيا كما وصفت إلى أن يتم أربع
>   ركعات، بتسليمة واحدة، فإذا فرغ لا يكلم أحدا، حتى يقرأ فاتحة الكتاب عشر
>   مرات، وإنا أنزلناه عشر مرات، ويسبح ثلاثا وثلاثين مرة، ثم يقول: صلى
>   الله على النبي الأمي، جزى الله محمدا عنا ما هو أهله ومستحقه، ثلاثا
>   وثلاثين مرة، من فعل هذا وجد ملك الموت وهو ريان، وذكر (عليه السلام) له
>   ثوابا جزيلا، ذكرناه في دار السلام (2).

[http://shiaonlinelibrary.com](http://shiaonlinelibrary.com/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A8/1242_%D9%85%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%83-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%88%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%8A%D8%B1%D8%B2%D8%A7-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%86%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%8A-%D8%AC-%D9%A6/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AD%D8%A9_0?pageno=393#top)

The authenticity cannot be determined because the author has not given the isnad for the Hadith.